# Implementation of x12 274 NM1 Provider record

Tags: edi, x12

I'm looking at page 62 of the spec and see
•   Syntax item P0809 (“If either NM108 or NM109 is present, then the other is required.”) 
•   The DIAGRAM section (and following text on page 63) indicates that both NM108 and NM109 are Required (not Situational) fields

Which seems to read:
Since NM108 or NM109 are Required, the fields must be present even if either is not valued
Syntax item P0809 placed the additional rule that if either are valued, but must be valued or both must be not valued

By these rules; these NM1 records are valid
NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T✽✽✽FI✽123456789~
NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T✽✽✽✽~

Where are these are not value
NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T✽✽✽FI✽~
(“If either NM108 or NM109 is present, then the other is required.”)

NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T✽✽✽✽123456789~ 
(“If either NM108 or NM109 is present, then the other is required.”)

NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T~ 
(NM108 and NM109 are Required fields)

I have a "discussion" going on with a consultant that
NM1✽1P✽1✽MARTIN✽NANCY✽T~
is right if NM108 or NM109 are not valued

I do not think this is right but I have this as a defect right now.  How should this logic go?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about EDI standards and not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: NM108 is a qualifier, meaning it qualifiers NM109.  You can't have one without the other.  NM108 describes NM109.  If NM108 and NM109 are not present, your NM1 as described would be correct.  It was typical not to send empty elements, especially when we were paying by the kc.

Comment: No ken...it goes directly to how you program the processing of this; understanding is critical

Comment: Andrew: Would you say
"It was typical not to send empty elements" unless the fields are marked "Required"?

Comment: You typically only send up to the last element used, regardless of mandatory/optional.  Sometimes we get wrapped up in those designations when the partner just bastardizes the standard anyway rendering the designation moot.

Comment: but then why is the field marked Required if you only have to send it if you only feel like sending it...or not..unless it's Tuesday...or john is sending it?  

Do commercial validators send Required fields that are not valued?

I'm having this conversation right now.  We are actually looking for Required fields.  I'm getting a file that is not putting in these fields if they are not valued.  I say the incoming file is not following the implementation

Comment: Andrew gives the right answer. There other little musing are just ....funny,

Comment: Commercial translators validate against the standard.  If your customer decides to change the requirement on the element, you'd have to build a custom dictionary to handle that.  (Not all translators support this feature).  The X12 standard != your partner's implementation of the standard.  I can only go by your question regarding having a qualified field without a qualifier would be invalid per the X12 standard.

Comment: Let me recap/restate just to be completely clear...I understand that "You typically only send up to the last element used, regardless of mandatory/optional" but "typically" does not always mean "correctly".  On the NM1 record, positions NM110, NM111 and NM112 are optional. If these are not valued, the line can be terminated after NM109 but not before.  NM103 is required.  According to the responses, I can terminate the record after NM102 if I want.  What does "Required" mean if that's the case?  Where in the spec does it say I can drop unvalued Required fields.

Comment: There is also Syntax rule C1110 ("If NM111 is present, then NM110 is required.") and neither NM110 nor NM111 are marked Required.  The Synatx rules for NM108 and NM109 are essentially the same as NM110 and NM111 but NM108 and NM109 are identified as "Required" and NM110 and NM111 are identified as "Situational"  While NM108 and NM109 can be NULL, they are Required so the delimiters need to be there even if the fields are not valued.  A little strange but it seems that this was intentional

Comment: in newer x12 versions composites are used, which i probably clearer. OK 08 en 09 'belong together': they need to be there !both!. (technically it is possible to use one of those, but the rule says you should not do that, it is nonsense. Same for 10 and 11: if one is used, the other should be used. Noow the data in 08 and 09 is required. The data in 10 and 11 is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code is as follows
`ValidP08P09 := Not ( IsEmpty(NM108) XOR IsEmpty(NM109) )`

Comment: Thanks, but that is only part of the answer, I need to understand if the delimiters need to be present for unvalued Required fields